Existence of $E(u)$; $E(u)=E(u^+-u^-)$

From chapter $IV.2$ of $$\textit{William Feller 'An Introduction 
to Probability Theory 
and Its Applications'; Vol.2}$$

$E(u)=\int_{\mathcal R^r}u(x)F\{dx\}$

I'm confused about the statement '$E(u)$ exists iff either $E(u^+)$ or $E(u^-)$ is finite'
We have that $u^+=u \cup 0 ; \; u^-=-u \cup 0$ and we can write $u$ as $u^+-u^-$. If both $E(u^+); E(u^-)$ are finite, then $E(u)=E(u^+-u^-)=E(u^+)-E(u^-)$ exists, but how can we assure that $E(u)$ exists given that either $E(u^+)$ or $E(u^-)$ is finite?

If $E(u^+)=\infty$ and  $E(u^-)=\infty$ then $E(u^+)-E(u^-)$ is undefined.  In all other cases $E(u^+)-E(u^-)$ is defined as  real number or $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

@geetha290krm, when you wrote $E(u^+)=\infty$ and $E(u^-)=\infty$, you're saying that $E(u^+)=+\infty$ and $E(u^-)=+\infty$?

Yes, for me $\infty$ without a sign is $+\infty$.

$u^-$ and $u^+$ are nonnegative so if $E(u^+)$ or $E(u^-)$ is infinite, that can only be understood as $+\infty$.
